# Sql Server script keeps on running

Tags: sql-server, loops, while-loop, sql-insert

I am writing a sql server migration script to copy over all cut calendars to sd calendars, with some small modifications. I wrote following script

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUT_CALENDAR) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT

    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID FROM CUT_CALENDAR

    INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR  (NAME, CALENDAR_ROLE_ID,DESCRIPTION,USE_IN_CUTOFF,PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS)
    SELECT NAME, CALENDAR_TYP_ID,DESCRIPTION,'Y',PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS
    FROM CUT_CALENDAR
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    DELETE FROM CUT_CALENDAR WHERE ID = @ID
END
GO
```

CUT_CALENDAR contains +- 30 records

But when I run this script, it keeps on running and I receive a:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I think this says that I've put an endless loop, but I can't see how.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you getting Java errors in SQL Server?

Comment: Why put in a loop? You can do this using a set-based approach.

Comment: Is the Autocommit ON?

Comment: What is autocommit?

Comment: @Felix, can you give an answer with a set-based approach?

Comment: just tried this code and it worked fine (cannot format comment. had to remove at sign..)
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUT_CALENDAR) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE ID INT

    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = I1 FROM CUT_CALENDAR

    INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR  (NAME)
    select name from  CUT_CALENDAR
    WHERE I1 = ID;
  
    DELETE FROM CUT_CALENDAR where I1 =ID 
END
GO

Comment: If you're getting a Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, it seems like when you get this recordset back to the application that's calling it, something is going wrong there.  Your SQL seems sound, I would investigate how you're handling it on the application side.  To test the SQL, PRINT the `select COUNT(*) from cut_calendar` on each loop and make sure the number is going down consistently (need to view in MS SQL Server).  EDIT: Assuming an application is calling it?  The OP makes me think maybe not...which confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Set Based" approach, try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sd_calendar (Columns)
SELECT
   (Columns)
FROM
   cut_calendar

DELETE FROM cut_calendar
```

There's no need to do it one by one, that just slows SQL down.  You're doing a straight copy and then delete from the original table, so do it using a bulk operation, like above, and you can cut down on the looping. If you're trying to affect everything, don't add a where clause.